# bokeh line chart with data markers from postgres DB

Tags: python, bokeh

the data rows looks like:

```
date    name    val
2017-02-05 a 600.0
2017-02-05 b 345.0
2017-02-05 c 679.0
2017-02-05 d 0.0
2017-02-05 e 66.0
2017-02-05 f 0.0
2017-02-05 g 156.0
2017-03-05 a 634.0
2017-03-05 b 0.0
2017-03-05 c 2679.0
2017-03-05 d 0.0
2017-03-05 e 9266.0
2017-03-05 f 0.0
2017-03-05 g 56.0
```

I'd like to produce a line chart with data markers. x would be date, y would be val and the legend color would be grouped by "name"

I wrote some code as below, but it shows me a blank page. It seems like something goes wrong. I'm also not sure how to add data markers. searched from internet and seems like should be merging a line chart and a circle chart in order to get it done.

could someone please help to fix the error and show me how to do this?

```
from bokeh.charts import Line, show, output_file, TimeSeries,Scatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd


# database credentials
usr  = 'test'
pswd = 'test'
db = 'test'


# create the connection to the database
engine = sa.create_engine(
    'postgresql://{0}:{2}@localhost:3552/{1}' \
    .format(usr,db,pswd)
)


query = "select date::text,name,round(size/1024/1024/1024) as val from test order by 1,2"

# extract the data
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)

output_file("example_chart.html")

# create a line chart where each column of measures receives a unique color and dash style
plot = figure(title="Example of a line chart", x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='size in GB')

plot.line(x=df['date'], y=df['val'], color=df['name'])

show (plot)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot comment Pablo's answer, I am adding mine based on his answer.
It was also blank for me and the issue came from the timestamp, you need to make sure that you are using DatetimeIndex in data affectation.

Here is my code extract from my class (I am not good at coding, so remarks are welcome) which takes data from postgresql and plot it:

```
def getColumn(self, column):
    self.logger.info('Getting ' + column +' from DB...')
    self.cur.execute("SELECT " + column + " FROM history")

    return [i[0] for i in self.cur.fetchall()]

def multiAccountsPlot(self):

    #I sort the blank issue by making sure the dates format was the same as Pablo's sample
    data = np.array([pd.DatetimeIndex([i.isoformat() for i in self.getColumn("timestamp")]),
        self.getColumn("account"), 
        self.getColumn("amount")])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data.T,columns = ["date","account","amount"])

    p = bokeh.plotting.figure(width=800, height=350, x_axis_type="datetime")
    dates = [df[df.account.isin([x])].date for x in df.account.unique()]
    vals = [df[df.account.isin([x])].amount for x in df.account.unique()]

    mypalette=Spectral11[0:len(df.account.unique())]
    p.multi_line(xs=dates,ys=vals, line_color=mypalette)

    bokeh.io.output_file("example_chart.html")
    bokeh.io.show(p)
```

Thanks Pablo for your answer, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that you are reading the color from the df indicates me that you might want to plot several lines. If that is the case you should use `multi_line` instead of `line`. See

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#multiple-lines

```
plot.multi_line(xs=df['date'], ys=df['val'], color=df['name'])
```

**Update**

Creating some data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.array([pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-02-05']*7+['2017-03-05']*7),
["red","green","blue","orange","black","yellow","purple"]*2,
[600.0,345.0,679.0,0.0,66.0,0.0,156.0,634.0,0.0,2679.0,0.0,9266.0,0.0,56.0]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data.T,columns = ["date","name","val"])
```

that looks like this:

[image]

I've changed the column name to actual colors. Then you need to rearrange your data in order to use multi_line:

```
import bokeh
import bokeh.plotting

p = bokeh.plotting.figure(plot_width=300,plot_height=300, x_axis_type="datetime")
dates = [df[df.name.isin([x])].date for x in df.name.unique()]
vals = [df[df.name.isin([x])].val for x in df.name.unique()]
p.multi_line(xs=dates,ys=vals, color = df.name.unique())

bokeh.io.output_file("example_chart.html")
bokeh.io.show(p)
```

The output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Hi Pablo, still blank chart.

Comment: This would help me help you and probably yourself before: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Pablo, I replaced the original line "plot.line" with the "multi_line" function you advised. The python file can be executed with no error raised. However, the html page opened is blank. It's got the title of the plot and the a grey box, inside it should have line chart but it's empty.

Comment: Well. I've written an example based on your data that only focuses on bokeh displaying the available data. I've not tested the postgres DB, which could be where the problem relies.